# Write string inside HTML attribute written inside string - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string

I want to write string inside a HTML attribute which is written inside jQuery string.

```
$htmlcode += '<td><select onchange="getCompanyBySiteId('#search_state'' + row.candidate_id + ', this.value)"></select></td>';
```

This is my unsuccessful attempt.
Any idea how can I pass string parameter to `getCompanyBySiteId` function

Comment: Use `.on('change'` instead

Comment: You need to know which parts are inside the string and which parts outside and then which parts are inside a quote inside the string.  If you need to use a `'` or `"` inside the string, then use `\"` / `\'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to escape the `#search_state` part:

```
htmlcode += '<td><select onchange="getCompanyBySiteId(\'#search_state\'' + row.candidate_id + ', this.value)"></select></td>';
```